# Работает ли приложение на Android телефоне, если погас экран?

Tags: android, java, экран

Работает ли приложение, если погас экран?
Или как сделать, чтобы приложение продолжало работу, даже при погасшем экране, пишу на JAVA

Comment: "Работает" - в контексте Android понятие широкое. Прочитайте, опять же, про жизненный цикл Activity, LowMemoryKiller, Broadcasts и сервисы.

Answer (score 3):

смотря что ты имеешь ввиду под " продолжало работу, даже при погасшем экране"  в целом да,  экран гаснет в целях энергосбережения, но возможно ты имеешь в виду [Service уроки на русском](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/157-urok-92-service-prostoj-primer.html),  [Service документация](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Service.html)

---

могу предположить что когда приложение переходит в энергосбережения activity либо уничтожается, либо как то приостонавливается ... не за рабочей машиной не могу проверить, почитай про PowerManager и что происходит при переходе приложения в эенергосберегающй  режим
попробуй не просто Thread, а  Handler, или AsyncTask

Comment: Я написал простой таймер, работающий в потоке, в эмуляторе он работает нормально, то есть отсчет времени правильный, а вот заливаю на планшет, и когда экран гаснет, то сигнал окончания таймера не срабатывает(

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(100);
в отдельном потоке после 100секунд приложение должно пикнуть, но экран гаснет и все(

Comment: таймер работает в отдельном сервисе или просто отдельным потоком? В втором случае поток легко может умереть, как только приложение будет свернуто. И это в абсолютно нормально. При выключении экрана поток также может быть завершен.

Answer (score 1):

```
только что имел ту же проблему. результат:
1. когда запускал таймер через Handler.postDelayed в потоке UI - он засыпал при отключении экрана.
2. стал запускать в отдельном Thread - всё ок. 
проверял в разных вариантах - тёмный экран, свёрнутое приложение... 
пока в Activity не отработает onDestroy, - таймер жив.
Тестил на Samsung, HTC, ZTE, везде Android 4+.
На всяк случ код:

Thread standUp = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        // ...
    }
}
});
standUp.start();
```